# Record Surround Sound While Gaming

Tags: audio

Is there any software to capture surround sound when gaming? If not are there any hardware capture devices that can do this?

OBS, Shadow Play, and Elgato all appear to be unable to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[Audacity](http://manual.audacityteam.org/man/tutorial_recording_audio_playing_on_the_computer.html) is also able to record system sound, is open source and have support on several systems, although on some systems it may not be able to record the surround sound, maybe just the stereo mix. It relies on tools that create loopback inputs for the system outputs.

You also can connect each output of your surround sound card to a multi channel audio interface and record using a DAW like Reaper, Logic ProX, etc.. or even Audacity. But I think that record system sound is always better since you don't need to use wires.